# Problema al realizar diseño de base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, diseño

Estoy haciendo un sistema en laravel, y  uno de los cruds son Sectores. Voy a tener el nombre del sector y una imagen asociada al sector. A su vez un sector puede tener asociado varios sectores, como una jerarquía por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacer las tablas para asociar un sector con varios sectores.

Porque voy a tener una tabla Sector con campos Nombre, Simbolo. Y después tendría que empezar a crear subsectores? o como se podría manejar esa asociación.

Answer (score 3):

Pues para cumplir tus requerimientos tendrías que diseñar una base de datos así:

```
 ----------- ----------- ------------- ---------------
| SECTOR    |           |             |               |
|-----------|-----------|-------------|---------------|
| id        | 1         | 2           | 3             |
| nombre    | Sector XX | Sector XX.x | Sector XX.x.x |
| simbolo   | XX        | XX.x        | XX.x.x        |
| jerarquia | 1         | 2           | 3             |
| sector_id | null      | 1           | 2             | // este es el padre de un sector
 ----------- ----------- ------------- ---------------
```

Luego en tu clase modelo:

**Sector.php**

```
...

public function subsectores(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sector');
}
```

Y ahora puedes acceder a los subsectores así:

```
$subsectores = App\Sector::find(1)->subsectores;
```